# How to us html <img src> to display an image in laravel?

Tags: image, laravel, laravel-5.4, src

I am trying to src an image into my html. Using Laravel as a backend.

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="storage/app/public/photos/{{$photo}}" alt="Card image cap">
```

I have also used the system link command and tried,

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="storage/{{$photo}}" alt="Card image cap">
```

In the past this would have been sufficent however, when using Laravel this does not link the image.

Does Laravel not allow direct 'src' links, or am I messing up the 'src' file structure?

Comment: Try `<img class="card-img-top" src="storage/app/public/photos/{{$photo}}" alt="Card image cap">`

Comment: Is it working now, or why did you change the question to include the answers?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel uses [blade syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#displaying-data), variables (`$`) need to be between `{{ }}` in order to output their value.

So give `<img class="card-img-top" src="storage/app/public/photos/{{ $photo }}" alt="Card image cap">` a try :)

Answer (score 0):

Correct file path is:

```
src="storage/photos/{{photo}}"
```

It skips /app/public

Answer (score 0):

i think the simple call like

`<img src="storage/image/{{$data->photo}}" alt="">`

$data = result from foreach
photo = column in db.

Answer (score -1):

src="{{ url('assets/img') }}/{{ $item->photo }}"

Works for me!